# Rendering bug in search results

Tags: bug, search, markdown, mathjax

When searching for answers on [Bioinformatics.SE](http://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com), I noticed a weird little framed box pop up in the results list:

[image: screenshot]

The box turns out to be a MathJax box, and the code being displayed happens to be Perl code; apparently the `$` sigils in the Perl code snippet are somehow interpreted as MathJax delimiters in Markdown, even though the code fragment is nested inside a code block. It therefore seems that the truncated preview text is insufficiently escaped.